# How to iterate over changing set of children

Tags: javascript, children

I'm using vanilla javascript to iterate over the children of an element, removing them, based on a class.  However, I'm getting hung up on handling nested elements.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
var replacements = [];
var children = el.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    if(should_delete(child)) { /*just checking for the class "delete-me"*/
        replacements.push(child.outerHTML);
        var filler = document.createComment('deleted');
        child.parent.replaceChild(child);
    }
}
```

at the end of this, I need to have an element containing comments where replacements occurred, and an array of replaced values that matches the set of comments, one to one.

however, I am having issues with the following html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="delete-me">test</div>
        <div class="delete-me">
            <div class="delete-me">test2</div>
            <div class="delete-me">test3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-me">test4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-me">test5</div>
</div>
```

The end result is supposed to be:

with the array:

```
[
    '<div class="delete-me">test</div>',
    '<div class="delete-me"><div class="delete-me">test2</div><div class="delete-me">test3</div></div>',
    '<div class="delete-me">test4</div>',
    '<div class="delete-me">test5</div>'
]
```

but instead, it seems to fail early, because the children pseudo-array keeps mutating on me, to match the changing state of the DOM.

How can I allow the children pseudo-array to change with the DOM, while still iterating over it smoothly, and not storing the content of elements that have already been replaced?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a live collection ,which will change out from under you; instead, try `querySelectorAll` which returns a static collection, or if all you want is the children, just a property like `children`.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a “live” NodeList, so when you modify the DOM, it’s updated. Changing it to `var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.getElementsByTagName('*'));` might help – it will make the loop stop doing at least one wrong thing, anyway – but I don’t understand what you mean by “not storing the content of elements that have already been replaced”. Does the intended result listed really match that…?

Comment: Too bad you're not using jQuery. `$('.delete-me').remove()` would be so much simpler. This being said, I'm not sure dashes are allowed in class names (should be `deleteMe`)

Comment: @torazaburo - I think I actually need a live collection, to do what I want, as I need to remove children (as seen in the nested example), and not iterate over them.  If my children object isn't live, when I remove an element its children are still in the set of children, and will still be processed

Comment: @ryan-ohara - see my earlier response to torazaburo.  I believe I need a live collection to NOT process nested children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

Rather than using either a live collection or a static array, I needed to recurse through the dom tree, deleting as I went.

```
var replacements = [];
var processChildren = function(children) {
    var children_a = []; // this array exists so that children wont change as we delete elements
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children_a.push(children[i])
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < children_a.length; i++) {
        var child = children_a[i];
        if(should_delete(child)) { /*just checking for the class "delete-me"*/
            replacements.push(child.outerHTML);
            var filler = document.createComment('deleted');
            child.parent.replaceChild(filler, child);
        } else {
            processChildren(child.children);
        }
    }
}
processChildren(el.children);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate backwards.

```
for( i = children.length-1; i>=0; i--)
```

This will ensure that, even if you end up deleting elements, each one will be seen in turn. You can even add elements and have it work just fine, so long as those added elements come after the one adding them.

Comment: this would cause me to iterate over children first, storing their value, before deleting them, without knowing that the parent needs to be deleted, so only the parent value should be stored.